# Segues similar to Apple's Clock app

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I want to segue between my view controllers the same way Apple's Clock app segues between the World Clock, Alarm, Bedtime etc. They just appear instantly, and most important of all, it doesn't instantiate new instances of the different parts (e.g. the Stopwatch and Timer keeps going after segueing).

I'm trying to prevent using a Navigation Controller, because I don't want a back button or anything to appear. I just want buttons that segue you to the other parts of the app without stopping timers etc.

If anyone could point me in the right direction in regards to this, I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: The Clock App likely instantiates new instances of the ViewControllers, but has separate model classes to keep the Stopwatch and Timer data going even if there isn't a view controller or view to display.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want to use a `UITabBarController`?

See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/TabBarControllers.html

Comment: That does the trick, but suppose I want the functionality of the UITabBarController (switching between different operations, as Apple puts it), but without the tab bar in the bottom, instead using only UIButtons. Would that be possible?

Comment: @MathiasJepsen You might want to search for "custom segues" to see if there is a way to use them without a navigation controller or tab bar controller. Or just remove a view controller from the window and add a new one.

Answer (score 1):

apple is using a UITabBarController over there
you can use that